# Extracting coordinates file that are inside a bounding box

Tags: java, performance, csv

I'm scanning a CSV file to see which values fit inside of a given box. The CSV file has X and Y coordinates, and the arguments to the function are the perimeters of a box (i.e, top, bottom, left side, right side). I don't want to use any external libraries; part of the purpose of this is to learn how to speed up code manually.

I'm fairly new to Java, so any input would be helpful. I'm trying to get this down to 100ms if possible, but right now it's taking about 1000ms.

```
Scanner dataStream = new Scanner(fileMain);
while (dataStream.hasNext()){
    String data = dataStream.next();
    String[] values = data.split(",", 3);
    if(Double.parseDouble(values[0]) > lowX && Double.parseDouble(values[0]) < highX){ 
            if(Double.parseDouble(values[1]) < highY && Double.parseDouble(values[1]) > lowY){
                System.out.println(data);

    }

dataStream.close();
```

Data is formatted like so:

```
90.92, 102.3
40.28, 82.32
13.02, 80
72, 104.82
```

Comment: In two places in this code you parse the same value as a double twice. Parse it once and save it.

Comment: @Racialz Comments are for seeking clarification. Please write that as an answer, even if it is just that short.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Do not vandalise your post, we are alerted to it in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and have to clean it up. This may result in a question ban. see [question bans](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: How many lines are there?

Comment: Can you supplement your question with the method declaration, so that we have a better sense of where the variables are coming from?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that you can always use [**`Point2D.Double`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) for representing points in a plane.

Next, I would split your program into two methods: the first one for pruning points that are not within a specified bounding box, and the second one for reading the points from the standard input, and putting them into the first one.

What comes to coding conventions, I would have a blank line before the **`if`** statement. Also, you should surround the condition of an **`if`** statement with a **single space**. So, instead of

```
String[] values = data.split(",", 3);
if(Double.parseDouble(values[0])){ ...
```

you should write

```
String[] values = data.split(",", 3);

if (Double.parseDouble(values[0])) { ...
```

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoordinateUtilities {

    public static List<Point2D.Double> 
        getPointsWithinBoundingBox(final List<Point2D.Double> pointList,
                                   final double lowX,
                                   final double highX,
                                   final double lowY,
                                   final double highY) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(pointList, "The list of points is null.");
        checkXBounds(lowX, highX);
        checkYBounds(lowY, highY);
        final List<Point2D.Double> ret = new ArrayList<>(pointList.size());

        for (final Point2D.Double point : pointList) {
            final double x = point.x;
            final double y = point.y;

            if (lowX <= x && x <= highX && lowY <= y && y <= highY) {
                ret.add(point);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final double lowX  = 50.0; 
        final double highX = 100.0;
        final double lowY  = 30.0;
        final double highY = 60.0;

        final List<Point2D.Double> allPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.trim().equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            final Point2D.Double point = parsePoint(line);

            if (point != null) {
                allPoints.add(point);
            }
        }

        final List<Point2D.Double> boundedPoints = 
                getPointsWithinBoundingBox(allPoints, lowX, highX, lowY, highY);

        boundedPoints.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Point2D.Double parsePoint(final String line) {
        final String[] tokens = line.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");

        if (tokens.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            final double x = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
            final double y = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void checkXBounds(final double lowX, final double highX) {
        if (Double.isNaN(lowX)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The lower bound of the x-coordinate is NaN.");
        }

        if (Double.isNaN(highX)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The upper bound of the x-coordinate is NaN.");
        }

        if (lowX > highX) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The lower bound of the x-coordinate (" + lowX + "is " +
                    "larger than the upper bound of the x-coordinate (" +
                    highX + ").");
        }
    }

    private static void checkYBounds(final double lowY, final double highY) {
        if (Double.isNaN(lowY)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The lower bound of the y-coordinate is NaN.");
        }

        if (Double.isNaN(highY)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The upper bound of the y-coordinate is NaN.");
        }

        if (lowY > highY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The lower bound of the y-coordinate (" + lowY + "is " +
                    "larger than the upper bound of the y-coordinate (" +
                    highY + ").");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.